# How to override EmbeddedNavigator_ButtonClick (XtraGrid)

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, xtragrid

I program in C#.NET and use the XtraGrid control in my App.

I use MyXtraGrid (customized control) in my project.

Now I need override `EmbeddedNavigator_ButtonClick` for custom buttons:

1. Export to Excel
2. Print and etc

But I dont use override methods for `EmbeddedNavigator_ButtonClick`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [EmbeddedNavigator.CustomButtons](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsNavigatorButtonsBase_CustomButtonstopic) property provides access to the collection of custom buttons. You can add all needed buttons into this collection.
To override the [Embedded Navigator](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridGridControl_EmbeddedNavigatortopic) buttons behavior or implement custom button's reaction you should handle the [NavigatorBase.ButtonClick](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsNavigatorBase_ButtonClicktopic) event.  Here is some sample code:

```
class MyGridControl : DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl {
    public MyGridControl() {
        EmbeddedNavigator.ButtonClick += EmbeddedNavigator_ButtonClick;
    }
    //...
    void EmbeddedNavigator_ButtonClick(object sender, NavigatorButtonClickEventArgs e) {
        if(e.Button.ButtonType == DevExpress.XtraEditors.NavigatorButtonType.Delete) {
            // ... your code is here
            e.Handled = true;  // disable the default processing
        }
        if(e.Button.ButtonType == DevExpress.XtraEditors.NavigatorButtonType.Custom) {
            // ... your code is here
            e.Handled = true;  // disable the default processing
        }
    }
}
```